# How to extract an element of an array and insert it in another while respecting its original index

Tags: arrays, ruby

How to combine 2 arrays like this

```
a = ["x","y","z"]
b = [["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"]]
```

expected output:

```
[["a","b","x" ],["c","d","y"],["e","f","z"]]
```

Is there any inbuilt method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is. You can use [Array#`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-zip) in conjunction with [Array#`flatten`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-flatten):

```
b.zip(a).map(&:flatten)
#=> [["a", "b", "x"], ["c", "d", "y"], ["e", "f", "z"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

another way is:

```
[b, a].transpose.map(&:flatten)
#=> [["a", "b", "x"], ["c", "d", "y"], ["e", "f", "z"]]
```

:)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more way to do this:

```
a = ["x","y","z"]
b = [["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"]]

b.map.with_index {|arr, idx| arr << a[idx]}
#=> [["a", "b", "x"], ["c", "d", "y"], ["e", "f", "z"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
enum = a.to_enum
b.map { |arr| arr << enum.next }
  #=> [["a", "b", "x"], ["c", "d", "y"], ["e", "f", "z"]]
```